# Output from table printing incorrectly JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project that will determine the time to pay off a credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made. I have been able to get my code to give me the correct balance, interest, and minimum payments, all the way until the last few lines that are displayed. I have been having some trouble getting my table to perform the proper output. I have tried changing around a few things but it still seems to display improperly. I am very new to JavaScript so I am still trying to learn the basics and any input would be greatly appreciated. I will add in a code snippet and a picture of what my table is supposed to look like. Thanks!

```js
function displayWelcome() {
  console.log("Welcome! \nThis program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.")
}

function calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate) {
  return Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
}

function displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {

  console.log("Balance on your credit card: $" + balance.toFixed(2))
  console.log("Interest Rate: " + (interest * 100) + "%")
  console.log("Assuming a minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)")
  console.log("Your minimum payment would be: $" + minimumPayment)
  console.log("\nYear    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid      Minimum Payment")

  var year = 1;
  var payments = 1;
  var interestPaid = 0;
  var yearChange;

  while (balance > 0) {
    yearChange = false;

    if (payments % 12 == 0) {
      year++
      yearChange = true;
    }
    interestPaid += balance * interest / 12;
    balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));
    minimumPayment = Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
    console.log(yearChange ? year : "" + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) + "      " + payments + "              " + interestPaid.toFixed(2) + "             " + minimumPayment.toFixed(2));
    payments++;
  }
}

var balance = 1500;
var minimumPaymentRate = 0.02;
var interest = 0.18;

displayWelcome()
var minimumPayment = calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate);

displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment);
```

I have added two pictures below of what I am seeing when I run the program and what the program is supposed to look like in the two links below.

This is the output I am receiving
[image]

This is how the table is supposed to look
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `console.log()` for formatted output? It's meant for debugging. Create an HTML table.

Comment: I have to use console.log() for my class. This is class is just an intro to JavaScript. We have not gotten into html.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is operator precedence. The `?:` conditional operator has lower precedence than `+`, so the `:` part contains all the concatenated strings, not just the `""` string that should replace the year. So you display the year when `yearChange` is true, you display everything else only when `yearChange` is false.

The solution is to wrap the conditional expression in parentheses.

```js
function displayWelcome() {
  console.log("Welcome! \nThis program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.")
}

function calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate) {
  return Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
}

function displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {

  console.log("Balance on your credit card: $" + balance.toFixed(2))
  console.log("Interest Rate: " + (interest * 100) + "%")
  console.log("Assuming a minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)")
  console.log("Your minimum payment would be: $" + minimumPayment)
  console.log("\nYear    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid      Minimum Payment")

  var year = 1;
  var payments = 1;
  var interestPaid = 0;
  var yearChange;

  while (balance > 0) {
    yearChange = false;

    if (payments % 12 == 0) {
      year++
      yearChange = true;
    }
    interestPaid += balance * interest / 12;
    balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));
    minimumPayment = Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
    console.log((yearChange ? year : "") + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) + "      " + payments + "              " + interestPaid.toFixed(2) + "             " + minimumPayment.toFixed(2));
    payments++;
  }
}

var balance = 1500;
var minimumPaymentRate = 0.02;
var interest = 0.18;

displayWelcome()
var minimumPayment = calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate);

displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment);
```

Comment: When I run the program it fixed most of the alignment but there are certain spots when scrolling through that the output is misaligned.

Comment: That's a format matter that wouldn't be a problem if you used a table instead of the console

Comment: @B.Moe09 That's because the space you put between the first two columns doesn't subtract the size of the year.